# openId login to stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm using myopenid to login to stackoverflow. myopenid is going to be shut down after February of 2014 and I want to see if there is a way I can still use my account and login using stackexchange. When I try to add my username and password using stackExchange login, that I use for myopenid it rejects it. If I try to use the email associated with the account and the myopenid password it also rejects it saying no such account with this email for stackExchange.

Anyone know if I can still use my account but login without using myopenid?